# Is a radio receiver antenna a capacitor?

Tags: electromagnetism, capacitance, electrical-engineering, antennas

I think so, but its capacitance should be very small, so how can the antenna correctly receive the signal, the low capacitance wont bother the signal?

Comment: there are many kinds of antennas: a capacitor resonant with an inductor can act as an antenna (electric dipole like) just as a a coil resonant with a capacitor could be one (magnetic dipole antenna).

Answer (score 2):

the capacitance and inductance of the antenna determine its electrical impedance. its impedance determines how much incident RF power will be converted into current flow in the antenna and how much will be reflected off it.

This is a much more significant issue if the antenna is being used to transmit RF power rather than receive it. For the case of a transmitting antenna, the antenna designer has to get an impedance match between the antenna, the feed line, and the transmitter at the frequency being produced by the transmitter. A good match may require the addition of small amounts of capacitance or inductance to the antenna structure in order to *tune* it.